# What's the equivalent to ${var:-defaultvalue} in fish?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, fish

Hello I am trying to translate my .bashrc to fish format almost done, mostly is clear on the documentation but this part is giving me a headache.. is so my gnupg works with my yubikey ssh etc etc..
The fish version is latest 3.0 under Arch GNU/Linux

original on BASH:

```
# Set SSH to use gpg-agent
unset SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]; then
  export SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/$UID/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
fi
echo "UPDATESTARTUPTTY" | gpg-connect-agent > /dev/null 2&>1
```

Mine half converted into fish:

```
set -e SSH_AGENT_PID
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]
  set -x  SSH_AUTH_SOCK="/run/user/$UID/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
end
echo "UPDATESTARTUPTTY" | gpg-connect-agent > /dev/null 2>&1
```

so as you see above I have so far converted the stdin and stderror pine and the unset variable with set -e  the error I am having is a bit more obscure to me:

```
~/.config/fish/config.fish (line 33): ${ is not a valid variable in fish.
if [ "${gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by:-0}" -ne $$ ]
       ^
from sourcing file ~/.config/fish/config.fish
        called during startup
```

Any help will be much appreciated,
BTW will be nice a migrate too :) are there any out there?

[edit] ok got this working thanks to the response below, now all my bash environment, profile, bashrc etc is translated to fish and using it solely as my shell 100%

Comment: A good question is about one narrow, *specific* problem -- so "how can I translate program-X to language-Y?" is a bad question, but "what's the language-Y way to write thing-X without triggering error-Z?" can be a good one. I've edited the title to narrow appropriately.

Comment: Always specify the version of the programs you are using. In this case fish 3.0 was recently released which has some differences relevant to your question from fish 2.x.

Comment: it is 3.0 I edited the question sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not change your login shell until you have a much better understanding of fish syntax and behavior. For example, in fish the equivalent of `$$` is `%self` or `$fish_pid` depending on which fish version you are using. You should always specify the version of the program you are having problems with.

Assuming you're using fish 2.x that would be written as

```
if not set -q gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by
or test $gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by -ne %self
    set -gx SSH_AUTH_SOCK "/run/user/$UID/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
end
```

Also, notice that there is no equal-sign between the var name and value in the `set -x`.

Comment: I'm using latest on arch so 3.0 but I suppose is backward compatible?

Comment: I have it all working, thanks! <3 note I had to create a $UID variable because fish does not gives you that, so created a set UID (id -u)

Answer (score 2):

Since `${var:-value}` expands to `value` if `$var` is empty, you can always replace it by writing your code out the long way:

```
begin
  if test -n "$gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by"
    set result "$gnupg_SSH_AUTH_SOCK_by"
  else
    set result 0
  end

  if [ "$result" -ne %self ]
    set -x SSH_AUTH_SOCK "/run/user/$UID/gnupg/S.gpg-agent.ssh"
  end
  set -e result
end
```

<sub>Note that I don't use (a) endorse, (b) condone the use of, or (c) fail to hold unwarranted prejudices against users of, fish. Thus, my advice is very much suspect, and it's likely that there are considerably better ways to do this.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar question, related to XDG_* variables.

```sh
var1="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}"/foo
var2="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}"/foo
var3="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/foo
some-command "$var1" "$var2" ...
```

What I found as the best alternative is to simply set univeral variables once for the defaults--

```
set -U XDG_CACHE_HOME ~/.cache
set -U XDG_CONFIG_HOME ~/.config
set -U XDG_DATA_HOME ~/.local/share
```

Then in fish config file(s) or scripts, simply use `"$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"/...`. The value of an exported environment variable will override the universal variable if set, otherwise the universal variable is there as a default/fallback. If the universal variable is used, it is not exported to child processes, while an exported environment variable is, which provides the full equivalent to bash|zsh parameter expansion.

Comment: My [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65529529/parameter-expansion-when-parameter-is-unset-or-null-like-bash-in-fish) was closed as a duplicate of this one, so I thought I'd share my findings here, even if my answer doesn't directly correlate to the exact question asked.