# parameter expansion when parameter is unset or null like bash in fish

Tags: bash, fish

Is there an equivalent (or [better|alternative] option) to bash's [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in fish?

Specifically, I'm looking for the `${parameter:-word}` "if parameter is unset or null" case.

I have a lot of lines such as these in various bash init scripts or shell scripts that I'm trying to find a reasonable alternative to.

```sh
var1="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}"/foo
var2="${XDG_DATA_HOME:-$HOME/.local/share}"/foo
some-command "$var1" "$var2"
```

I haven't found a better option yet than writing a lot of inline blocks such as this, which seems overly verbose.

```
begin
    test -z "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME" && set -l XDG_CONFIG_HOME "$HOME"/.config
    test -z "$XDG_DATA_HOME" && set -l XDG_DATA_HOME "$HOME"/.local/share
    set var1 "$XDG_CONFIG_HOME"/foo
    set var2 "$XDG_DATA_HOME"/bar
    some-command "$var1" "$var2"
end
```

I don't want to be required to have the XDG_* variables set in the environment-- I want to be able to use defaults if they are unset.